# Can I Tag Git commit with VisualStudio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to apply tag after merge within visual studio 2013 for a Git repository?
I'm looking for this action in the team explorer but I can't find it.

Thanks..

Comment: All the features of Git are available through command line. GUI’s and IDE’s usually provide only a subset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572.aspx) I'd say not currently. Although you are able to view them.

```
I want to: 
    Apply a tag to a commit

Can I do it in Visual Studio? 
    No, but you can view them. See View and manage past versions in Git.

How do I do it from the command prompt?
    You can use the command prompt to push, edit, and remove tags (see Git-scm: Git Basics - Tagging) from a repository in TFS if you have sufficient permissions.
```

Comment: thanks I decided to use sourceTree(Atlassian) in addition of Visual studio to manage branches and tags

Comment: VS team explorer plugin is very limited. I always have SourceTree open alongside with VS, and I do all branch management, history browsing, commits/pulls from SoureTree. MS products just can't follow

Answer (score 24):

You can now do it in VS 2015, in Team Explorer, go to sync --> outgoing commits --> double click an item to open.

You should see a 'Create Tag' action.

Alternately, if your branch is already synced, go to Branches --> Right-click on your current branch --> View History... --> Then right-click the commit you want to tag.

You should see a 'Create Tag' action.

These instructions work at least for VS 2015 Professional and Enterprise.

Comment: Although this worked for me to create the tag in VS 2015, I still had to drop to the git command line to push the tag to my VisualStudioOnline repo: `git push --tags`.  Using sync or push in Visual Studio would not push the newly created tag.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 with VSTS and it seems I'm also having this issue (created Tag in VS 2015 from History screen, but even after Sync, VSTS shows no Tags).
Has anyone found a solution to this or am I missing something? :o/

Comment: @JonComtois that git command makes all the difference, I'd suggest you add an answer that includes it.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2017 (`v15.3.5`), in the `Team Explorer` => `Branches` window, I can right-click on a branch. Then click on the `View History...` command. A new `Local History` window is opened. In that window, I can right click on a specific commit and hit the `Create Tag` command in the context menu.

Comment: "This worked for me".  More like, after 4-5 google searches this is the first actual solution I found.

Comment: What about assigning a currently existing tag to a specific commit?

Comment: But this does not allow you to assign the  same tag to different commits, for grouping purposes, after we delete our short term branches eventually.  Why is it that VS does not allow us to do this?